# Using "If cell contains #N/A" as a formula condition.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help on my Excel sheet. How can I declare the following `IF` condition properly?

```
if A1 = "n/a" then C1 = B1
else if A1 != "n/a" or has value(int) then C1 = A1*B1
```

Comment: are you asking for an excel formula or VBA code?

Comment: sorry if i wasnt clear, im asking for an excel formula :)

Comment: use IFNA Function for Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel for Mac 2011, Excel Online, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone, Excel for Android tablets, Excel Mobile, Excel for Android phones (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Input the following formula in `C1`:

`=IF(ISNA(A1),B1,A1*B1`)

***Screenshots:***

**When #N/A:**

[image]

**When not #N/A:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use IFNA(expression, value)

Comment: thanks for the mention of IFNA() function. could you please explain, how can it be used to solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 2):

"N/A" is not a string it is an error, try this:

```
=if(ISNA(A1),C1)
```

you have to place this fomula in cell B1 so it will get the value of your formula

Comment: I miss interpreted, question was not clear, but I am glad he found the answer

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative approach in Excel 2010 or later versions:

`AGGREGATE(6,6,A1,B1)`

In `AGGREGATE` function the first `6` indicates `PRODUCT` operation and the second `6` denotes "ignore errors"

[untested]

Answer (score 0):

use this formula to return the results for case of "FALSE"/"TRUE":

=IF(ISNA(A1)=TRUE, B1, A1*B1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).