# VLOOKUP formula in Excel VBA is not working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to make this formula work in VBA, but it keeps telling that "B2" is supposed to be the end of the statement. The code is provided below:

```
With Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=I2/VLOOKUP(A2&"B2", MARM!A:G, 7, 0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

If I want for the formula, when it is 0 or #N/A to leave the cell empty I used the code but it is not working.. Any ideas?

```
.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0))"
```

Comment: all `"` inside the string should be `""`: `"=I2/VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)"`

Comment: If I want the formula not to show 0 or #N/A i tried this but is not working... any idea why??  .Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0))"

Comment: For `#N/A` on VBA refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5143524/7690982) or on formulas [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963015/7690982).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

```
With Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
.Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(I2/VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),"""")=0,"""",IFERROR(I2/VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),""""))"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: It gives me an application defined or object defined error

Comment: Excuse me. Edited. Here you are.

Comment: and if I want the formula without I2/ then I just take it out and it works?

Comment: Yes. Note that using `"` character tips in this approach and So check out`Application.WorksheetFunction` approach.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I tried using .Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),"""")=0,"""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),""""))" but is not working ..

Comment: What is the problem? If possible, share your workbook file. I checked above, You write `I want for the formula, when it is 0 or #N/A to leave the cell empty`. Is your formula works right except `I2/VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)` returns `0` or `#N/A`? Else, Please edit and update your question with describe about using `LOOKUP` formula problem. How is it in a cell as direct formula? Please first check your formula directly in appropriated cell. Please edit and update your question.

Comment: Buddy I figured it out !! Thanks again for the help and sorry for bothering you again !